# TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined - Javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am trying to run the following code and I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 111)
```

The line in question would be:

```
perCampaignRows.push([STRATEGISTS[i][1],
```

and here's the full code.

```
var perCampaignRows = [];

for (var i = 0; i < STRATEGISTS.length; i++) {
    var accountIterator = MccApp.accounts()
        .withCondition("ManagerCustomerId = '" + STRATEGISTS[i][0] + "'")
        .get();

    var mccAccount = AdWordsApp.currentAccount();

    while (accountIterator.hasNext()) {
        var account = accountIterator.next();
        MccApp.select(account);
        Logger.log("Checking " + account.getName() + " - CID: " + account.getCustomerId());
        var campaignIterator = AdWordsApp.campaigns()
            .withCondition("Status = ENABLED")
            .get();

        var activeCampaigns = campaignIterator.totalNumEntities();

        if (activeCampaigns === 0) {
            Logger.log("No Active Campaigns");
            perCampaignRows.push([
                STRATEGISTS[i][1],
                STRATEGISTS[i][2],
                account.getCustomerId(), 
                account.getName(), 
                activeCampaigns, 
                '', 
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
            ]);
        }
        else {
            Logger.log(activeCampaigns + " Active Campaigns");
        }

        while (campaignIterator.hasNext()) {
            var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
            Logger.log("Campaign: " + campaign.getName());
            var mobileBid = checkPlatform(campaign);
            var isRotatingEvenly = checkAdRotation(campaign);
            var sitelinkData = checkSitelinks (campaign);
            var isUsingMobileAds = checkAds(campaign);
            var callExtData = checkCallExtensions(campaign);
            var isUsingAdSchedule = checkAdSchedules(campaign);
            var isSomewhatLimitedByBudget = checkBudgetLimitations(campaign);

            if (isUsingAdSchedule && isSomewhatLimitedByBudget) {
                var warnAboutBudgetAndSchedule = "TRUE";
            }
            else {
                var warnAboutBudgetAndSchedule = "FALSE";
            }

            Logger.log(perCampaignRows);

            perCampaignRows.push([
                STRATEGISTS[i][1],
                STRATEGISTS[i][2],
                account.getCustomerId(), 
                account.getName(), 
                activeCampaigns, 
                campaign.getName(), 
                mobileBid, 
                isRotatingEvenly,
                sitelinkData[0],
                sitelinkData[1],
                sitelinkData[2],
                isUsingMobileAds,
                callExtData[0],
                callExtData[1],
                warnAboutBudgetAndSchedule
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really get why it's not working, considering I am declaring the array at the beginning. It's also worth noting that I did declare STRATEGISTS as a multi-dimensional array, like this:

```
var STRATEGISTS = [
    ['346-963-8912','Brizza','Arcadio'],
    ['885-612-1069','Doria','Arcadio'],
    ['922-596-2785','Edgar','Arcadio']
]
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

As per request I added:

```
Logger.log(STRATEGISTS.length);
Logger.log(STRATEGISTS);
```

The first one logged 51, and the second one logged the variable as expected.

Thanks,

Comment: if you get that error, for fun do a `console.log(STRATEGISTS)`, because the engine is telling you that object does not exist.

Comment: It's taken out of context... Most likely, either it is declared after it is used or it is declared in another scope.

Comment: Full snippet: http://pastebin.com/i7T5sdHJ

Comment: You have a multiline statement, so you get the error message on the first line of the statement. Likely candidates to be undefined are `sitelinkData` and `callExtData`, as you access them with an index of 0.

Comment: Try replacing `callExtData[0]` and `sitelinkData[0]` with something like `null` instead to identify the culprit. Alternatively, try assigning `callExtData[0]` and `sitelinkData[0]` to a new variable before the statement and use the variable instead to narrow down suspicious code regarding the error line number.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Guffa I realized that even though I had broken the push statement into different lines, it was treated as one. I had thought the problem was with my .push implementation, but rather it was a problem with one of the variables being pushed.

It turns out I had missed a return on

```
var callExtData = checkCallExtensions(campaign);
```

and so callExtData was empty, hence undefined.

Thanks!